# Difference between IIFE and regular function (example)

Tags: javascript

Learning about IIFEs i understand that using them does:

- not pollute the global scope
- shields your code from others.

Could someone please help me understand it better and give a real example of when i could get in trouble when using regular function statement (instead od IIFE?)

Comment: You mean IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Expression?

Comment: Outside of the modules, (almost) every script should be closed inside an IIFE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you have a decent sized codebase (a few thousand lines or more). Putting every function on the top level won't be a good idea, because then it'll be *pretty easy* to accidentally write a function name twice, which will cause bugs due to the name collision. For example:

```
// code around validating user registration
function validate(username) {
  return /someValidationRegex/.test(username);
}
// do stuff with validate


// And then, far elsewhere in the code,
// you need to validate an input for sending to the server:
function validate(input) {
  return /someOtherValidationRegex/.test(input);
}
// do stuff with validate
```

This will not work, because the last `validate` function will overwrite the first `validate` function, and the code won't work as expected.

Put each segment of code into an IIFE instead, to avoid the possibility of name collisions:

```
(() => {
  // code around validating user registration
  function validate(username) {
    return /someValidationRegex/.test(username);
  }
  // do stuff with validate
})();

(() => {
  // code around validating an input for sending to the server:
  function validate(input) {
    return /someOtherValidationRegex/.test(input);
  }
  // do stuff with validate
})();
```

This is the technique that [Stack Overflow's Javascript uses](https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/full.en.js) (at least in some parts).

Another reason to use IIFEs even if you're careful not to duplicate function names is that you may accidentally duplicate a *window property*. For example, the following is a somewhat common bug people run into:

```js
// name is defined to be a number...
var name = 5;
// but it's actually a string???
console.log(typeof name);
```

The problem here is that you're accidentally referring to / overwriting the `window.name` property on the top level, and `window.name` *may only be a string*. There are a whole bunch of functions and variables defined on the top level. To avoid name collisions, put everything into an IIFE instead:

```js
(() => {
  // name is defined to be a number...
  var name = 5;
  // And it's still a number, good
  console.log(typeof name);
})();
```

Still, if your codebase is large enough that name collisions are a decent possibility, rather than manually writing IIFEs, I'd highly recommend using a module system instead, like with Webpack. This will allow you to write modules inside their own encapsulated scope, without leakage or name collisions, *and* will be more maintainable, when each module only contains *exactly the code it needs to run*, and nothing more. This makes identifying bugs and extending features much easier than one huge long `<script>` that you have to navigate through manually.

Comment: Regarding the point of "you may accidentally duplicate a window property", y cant we just use a regular function, since variables are function scoped. Is there any reason to use an IIFE over a regular function, regarding that point, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The common advantage of [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is that any "Function or Variable" defined inside [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), cannot be accessed outside the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) block, thus preventing global scope from getting polluted.

[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)'s are used to define and execute functions on fly and use them on the spot without extra line of Code.

```js
(function(){
  var firstName = 'Jhon';
  console.log(firstName);
})(); // will be executed on the fly

function test(){
  var firstName = 'Jhon';
  console.log(firstName);
}
test(); // has to call manually
```

Answer (score 1):

The IIFE will actually run (immediately-invoked function expression), they don't need a trigger or function call to initiate them, so the variable will be set to its response.

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate this:

```js
var iffe = (function() {
    return 'foo';
})();

var func = function() {
    return 'bar';
};

console.log('iife = ' + iffe);
console.log('non-iife = ' + func);
```

In your JS console you'll see something similar to:

> iife = foo  and
>
> non-iife = function () {
>       return 'bar'; }

Also in case we need to pass something in the IFFE scope from the outer scope we need to pass them as a parameter and receive this inside the function defined in the IFFE wrap, something like this -:

```
var iffe = (function(doc) {
    return 'foo';
})(document);
```

This is a link for some more reference - http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/